# First mobile hybrid app questions-frameworks

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, cordova, frameworks, backend

I'm starting to build my very first mobile application but I'm quite confused with some of the concepts.

I'm gonna need a framework with mobile platform wrappers such as
- cordova
- intel app framework
Such a framework is used for taking advantage of native capabilities (camera, notifications etc)?

Along with the framework, I'm thinking of using backbone.js library which implements the MVC model. 
Also, what does JQuery (or zepto.js) offer?
I found the qooxdoo library for DOM maniplation as well.

All those things I mentioned apply to the frontend development? How do i proceed with developing the backend of my application?

To sum up, do i need all of these things? Is there anything I should add to these?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I actually need to know what kind of "tools" I'm gonna have to use for mobile hybrid app development. A library for this and that, a framework for this..

Comment: Hi.  This is a very broad question.  Any way you can divide it up into more concrete issues.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what kind of app you are trying to build. You will need a Mobile UI framework to develop the app and a tool to build hybrid app for various devices.

For Mobile UI framework, you can use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), [Intel AppFramework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/), [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), KendoUI or one of many other Mobile App frameworks out there. MVC framework can be used if your app is complex and uses data sources to dynamically load content.

If your app requires a backend for saving data on server, retrieving data or processing data, then you will have to setup some kind of backend with database, or you can use service like [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/)

If you want to access device features, then you will need to use [Cordova API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/index.html) or [Intel XDK APIs](http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/492826) to access device sensors like accelerometer, compass, camera....

As far as tools for building, you can use [Cordova SDK](http://cordova.apache.org/), [PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com/), Sencha Touch, [Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/) or others to build cross-platform hybrid apps.

Cordova SDK is most commonly used tool for building hybrid apps, build.phonegap.com provides the capability to build in the cloud.

Intel XDK is a complete tool to build mobile hybrid app, it allows you to choose from a bunch of mobile UI frameworks to design an app, it has a code editor, emulator to test, device testing capability, debugging and can build hybrid app for multiple platforms.

Comment: From what I've read, AppFramework is a good framework, but JQuery Mobile provides more support and documentation.

So I'm gonna be needing a Mobile UI Framework to design my app (frontend), a tool like Cordova SDK to wrap to devices, an API to access the device and a database service. 

Apart from parse.com which is a paid service what other solution are there for backend? Is NoSQL a solution?

MVC framework needed for dynamic load content. DOM manipulation is needed?

Intel XDK provides all the above under one roof?

Comment: For most backend server, you will have to pay, amazon web services is most common, but you will have to setup server from scratch. You can use other services like Google appengine or Heroku for deploying backend. Parse is a service that does all the setup and provides APIs to access frontend. I think initially it is all free up to 1M api calls. DOM manipulation is usually required or included with mobile UI framework. Yes, Intel XDK is a complete app development solution, but there is no backend service.

Comment: So I could use XDK and connect it with any of the above backend tools.

Otherwise I can use Parse, Kendo UI and such to do all the things together.

OR I could use a UI framework, along with a mobile device wrapper and connect it to some backend service to get the work done.

These are the distinct choices right?

Comment: YES backend, frontend and build tools are all independent, you can use any combination. Only the device APIs are dependent on build tools, example: Cordova APIs will work with Phonegap build tool. Cordova API and Intel XDK APIs will work with Intel XDK tool.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Monaca](http://monaca.mobi/en/). Monaca consists of many tool for developing mobil apps such as jQuery mobile, PhoneGap (for camera, notification ..), IDE, cross-platform development (iOS, Android and Windows 8) and etc. What you need to learn are just HTML5, Javascript and CSS.